# 'function' object has no attribute 'grab'

Tags: python, attributes, python-imaging-library, spyder

I was searching how to make a basic bot on games and I found this video, however the video doesn't explain well and i've got a problem no one had.
The video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Jwd69MRYwg
my problem :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoaXJ.png)

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps
import pyautogui, time
from numpy import *

class cordinates():
    replaybtn = (480,375)
    dino = (378,245)
    obstacle = (300,395)

def restartgame():
    pyautogui.click(cordinates.replaybtn)

def pressspace():
    pyautogui.keyDown("space")
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print('jump')
    pyautogui.keyUp('space')

def ImageGrab():
    box = (cordinates.dino[0]+78,cordinates.dino[1],cordinates.dino[0]+100,cordinates.dino[1]+30)
    image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    grayimage = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    a = array(grayimage.getcolors())
    return a.sum()

while True :
    ImageGrab()

restartgame()
time.sleep(1)
pressspace()
```

So when i try to use the grab function, it says there is no attribute grab but i dont understand because it should works like this..
thanks

Comment: Do you understand what `attribute` means in this context? If not, I can update my answer to explain.

Comment: ImageGrab.grab() works only with OS X and Windows, https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageGrab.html. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
def ImageGrab():
    box = (cordinates.dino[0]+78,cordinates.dino[1],cordinates.dino[0]+100,cordinates.dino[1]+30)
    image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
```

Because you are trying to use the name `ImageGrab` for your own function, the code inside `ImageGrab.grab` tries to find the `.grab` attribute *of that function*, rather than looking at the `ImageGrab` module. (This definition also prevents *other* code in your file from using the module.)

You need to choose a different name for this function. (While you're fixing names, `coordinates` should have two `o`s.)